# How to improve the iPhone battery?

Tags: iphone, battery

Hi all I was looking for a solution to prolong my battery life potential.

Is there a replacement battery for iPhone that is more powerful than the one in-built when we bought it?

Or is there an "external battery" that I can plug into my phone to increase the battery life potential?

Comment: Short answer would be yes. But which iPhone model do you have?

Comment: @iskra mine's a iPhone-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get external iPhone batteries.

Amazon will have very many products.

Answer (score 0):

I normally try to turn off several items to improve the battery life on my iPhone. My 5's battery life was terrible but then shut off several items and now lasts for about a day & half between charges.

Turn off the following: LTE, Wi-Fi, GPS (only on specific apps), dim display, bluetooth, 1 minute auto-lock screen conserves power, and if all else fails buy a car & office charger to get you through the day.

Here is [an article](http://mobilecasedirect.com/blogs/news/7127578-7-tips-how-to-increase-battery-life-iphone-5) that goes more in depth about conserving battery.